# jquery redirect without reload page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

I have two page One is front part and other is back part. front part have all of my data including db. and back part keeps only a php calendar which renders events from db. Calendar page is included into archive div in front part. calendars navigation month links next and prev both are anchor. and this anchors href like:

```
"calendar.php?month=<?php echo($prev_month.'&amp;year='.$prev_year); ?>"
```

and

```
"calendar.php?month=<?php echo($next_month.'&amp;year='.$next_year);?>".
```

[image]

when clicked on next or prev links its redirect to calendar page. Is it possible to load calendar data without redirect calendar page into my archive div in front part? and how to do it?

Im try Jquery Like this but failed...

```
$('#prev').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('.calendar').html('Loading ...').fadeIn();
jqXHR = $.post(url,{},function(data){
   jqXHR.done(function(){
        $('.calendar').html(data).fadeIn();
   });
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: Please Give a working example i'm knowledge less about ajax

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/